# JDK の更新がうまくいかない

Tags: java, eclipse

これまでjdk-11.0.17.8-hotspotでプログラミングしてました(なぜこれを選んだか、特には理由がない)。

- 上記にはhotspotとついてますが、jdk-11と同じですか？
- jdk-21(あるいはもっと最新のやつ)に更新したいのですが、上手くいきません。

jdk-21では `/*・・・*/` や `//・・・(説明文)` をエラーとみなしていて、慌てて元の11に戻しました。このままで良いのか、あるいは別の良い方法があるのか分からないのでご教授願います。

Answer (score 1):

> - 上記にはhotspotとついてますが、jdk-11と同じですか？

Hotspot とは、[Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9B%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9D%E3%83%83%E3%83%88)

> オラクル（旧サン・マイクロシステムズ）によるJava仮想マシンの実装[4]およびそれが持つ最適化技術の名称

にある通りです。
現在はこのオラクル実装がデファクトスタンダードであり、明示的に言及しない限りJDK/JVMといえばこれを指すと考えて良いです。
(その他の実装としてはOpenJ9などがあります。 [参考](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59295177/4506703))

> - jdk-21(あるいはもっと最新のやつ)に更新したいのですが、上手くいきません。

eclipse タグが付いているので Eclipse IDE 上で開発しようとした場合に発生した問題である前提で回答しますが、現時点でリリースされている Eclipse IDE はそのままでは Java21 に対応していません。

1. Eclipse 最新版(2023-09 (4.29)) ([ダウンロードリンク](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/))をインストールした上で、
2. [Java 21 Support アドオン](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-21-support-eclipse-2023-09-429) を導入する

必要があります。

Comment: 丁寧な回答、有難うございました。

Comment: 補足：
>現在はこのオラクル実装がデファクトスタンダード
Oracleライセンス問題が付きまとう上にころころ変わるので、特にエンタープライズではOpenJDKを利用するのが最近のトレンドではないかなと思います。

ビルドとサポートについては
RHEL、Microsoft、Amazonなどが独自のビルド版を提供しています。

どちらかというと「デファクトスタンダード」といよりは「リファレンス実装」というのが近いかなと。。
かつてのJavaEEに対するGlass fishの様に